# reduce redundancy in swift UIView

Tags: swift, uiview

Anyway to add both horizontalLine and verticalLine to the UIView at the same time. The following way looks redundant.

```
var horizontalLineView : UIView = UIView(frame: horizontalLine)
var verticalLineView : UIView = UIView(frame: verticalLine)
```

Comment: You can omit the `: UIView` type specification. Swift will infer the type from the right hand side of the assignment. (Also try using `let` vs `var` when possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're doing it right. That's the most concise way to create the UIViews.

Potentially, you could create a pretty simple UIView extension that creates multiple lines in a single call but you're not really getting much for that effort.

```
extension UIView {

    static func createLines(frames:CGRect...) -> [UIView] {
        // create empty array for views
        var lines:[UIView] = []

        // loop over each frame provided
        for frame in frames {
            // create a UIView with that frame
            lines.append(UIView(frame: frame))
        }
        // return the lines
        return lines
    }

}

let horizontalLine = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 1)
let verticalLine = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 100)

// create the UIViews with one or more frames
let lines = UIView.createLines(horizontalLine, verticalLine)
```